# How to concatenate two or more column values and show them in a single column in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I have a requirement where we have added a new column to our vendor_implementation as implementation_name. I have to set this filed by combing two other fields in vendor_implementation table where field names are  and type. The query is below, the result should like "**Client create date 12/11/2017**" Client(type) + create date(string) 12/11/2017(create_date). I have to insert a static string **create date** between the type and create_date. How can I achieve the below requirement.

```js
UPDATE vendor_implementation
SET vendor_implementation.implementation_name = vendor_implementation.type + ' Created Date '  + TO_Char(vendor_implementation.create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: Why was a field added which is a combination of other fields, along with some static text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `type` column is a also `string`

```
UPDATE vendor_implementation v
   SET v.implementation_name = v.type ||' Created Date '|| TO_Char(v.create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL dialect uses `||` instead of `+`.